# What could be the reason Flash doesn't respond on local Zend_amf services?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, zend-framework, zend-amf, netconnection

I've (actually my classmate) got a problem with loading local ZEND_AMF services on Windows 7 (XAMPP). I can't find any answer on Google or on Stackoverflow. I found one similar topic without any answers: [ActionScript 3 AMF Zend fails silently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201474/actionscript-3-amf-zend-fails-silently)

Let me describe the problem: I've developed the UI and dataloading for a Memory(matching) Game in FLASH CS5. The games uses data from an ZEND Framework website (you can add levels/cards/images there).
IT happens like this:

```
var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
nc.connect("http://localhost/MemoryGame/public/service/gateway");
var res:Responder = new Responder(returnDataList,returnError);
nc.call("Service_GatewayService.getWorldsList",res);
```

Everything works fine on my Macbook Pro (Using MAMP as local server), but a classmate (who's helping with it) of me that is using a Windows 7 laptop with XAMPP doesn't see anything. We're both using Flash CS5.5.

For some reason his Flash isn't able to load local services. When he uses the same URL path like me Flash doesn't do anything in the responder. No Error function call and No Complete function call. We've been searching for the cause and tried several things.

In a ZEND_AMF tutorial on the Internet we've found an online AMF Service and put that in the code. Of course we're using a nonexisting service function so the responser will call the Error function. And yes, this works. He runs the function `returnError()`.

The cause of this problem is obvious: Flash on my classmates PC (using XAMPP) won't load local services.

Does anyone know a solution for this?

What isn't the solution:

- Allowing swf to correspond with non-local URLs (is an option where you have to add your swf to the Flash settings) => Has happened

Comment: maybe lower/upper case letters get confused on the windows machine ... try using a proxy tool like [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to debug the application and check whether or not the server responded with result/error or didn't respond at all.

Comment: That isn't the problem. We've changed the service url to lowercase and it still doesn't work on my classmates PC.
Any other possible solutions?

Comment: After two days of hard search, we found the problem ourselves.
In the service controller we redirect to the AMF action.
On Mac this doesn't give a problem en Flash waites for the redirect.
On Windows he doesn't wait i guess. We filled the action after the service url and now it both work on windows and mac. 
What a lame difference between two OS's.
@pkyeck thx for taking time to answer.

P.S. Can i point this comment as an answer for the question?

Comment: you can answer the question yourself, then wait for a day and accept it as the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days of hard search, we found the problem ourselves. In the service controller we redirect to the AMF action. On Mac this doesn't give a problem en Flash waites for the redirect. On Windows he doesn't wait i guess. We filled the action after the service url and now it both work on windows and mac. What a lame difference between two OS's.